# Change directory to execute a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cwd

In my script I create a directory
and need to execute subsequent commands within the directory.

The below script creates a directory, but the next script it invokes
(`repo init`) does not get executed within that directory.

```
mkcdir ()
{
    echo "creating directory" $1
    mkdir -p -- ~/"$1" &&
      cd -P -- ~/"$1"
}

mkcdir $1
repo init -u git@github.com:P0/manifest.git -b refs/tags/$1
repo sync
```

Comment: The respective folder is not in $PATH: `./repo ...`

Comment: If you place `echo $PWD` after `mkcdir $1` you should see the current directory in output. Also if directory already exists when your script runs `mkdir` fails and  `cd` won't be executed. Remove `&&` if you want to run next command regardless the success of previous.

Comment: @sebasth no, with the `-p` option `mkdir` won’t fail if the directory already exists, so the `&&` conjunction is fine here.

Comment: How do you know the `repo` script is not executed within the directory? What does this `repo` script exactly?

Comment: It is going to be very difficult to give a definitive answer from such inadequate information.  As sebasth suggests, put ``echo "$PWD"`` (or simply `pwd`) after the `mkcdir`, then post a transcript of an execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is almost correct. This is the corrected version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkcdir ()
{
    echo "creating directory" "$1"
    mkdir -p -- ~/"$1" &&
      cd -P -- ~/"$1"
}

mkcdir "$1"
repo init -u git@github.com:P0/manifest.git -b refs/tags/"$1"
repo sync
```

Note the double quotes around the `$1` on line 9 and around the `$1` on line 10. If you don't have those, word splitting (amongst other stuff) will occur, causing the arguments to `mkcdir` to split up. I also put quotes around `$1` on line 4, because although nothing bad will happen (it's just an `echo` command after all) certain expansion types could lead to confusion. For example, if `$1` contained an asterisk (`*`), it would expand to all files in the current directory, which is certainly not what you were looking for.

Other than that, a hashbang on the first line is not a bad idea, but it shouldn't really matter, especially if you're using bash anyway.

Comment: You have identified *improvements* to the script (although, for line 4, you could just say ``echo "creating directory $1"``).  But calling this an answer and saying that you have “corrected” the script is an unwarranted stretch.  Yes, if the OP’s directory name includes whitespace and/or other special characters, then their inadequate quoting is certainly a big problem.  But until we know how and why the script fails, it’s premature to say that this is the answer.

Comment: @G-Man I agree, I answered prematurely. However, as the standings are now, I think the answer is okay - we've been waiting for a response from OP for a while now. I've executed the script (the `repo` OP uses is https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo), and it works correctly with adequate quoting. It could be that OP doesn't fully profit from this answer, but someone with a similar problem might. If he edits, I'll certainly agree to delete/edit this answer as well.